# How to write test case using mockito and junit for ExecuterService in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, mockito, executorservice

How to write test case using mockito and junit for ExecuterService?

```
protected void updateRequest(String request) {

      ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
      executor.submit(() -> {
          service.callGattuService(request);
      });

      executor.shutdown();
}
```

Earlier this method was not Multithreaded and service.callGattuService() was called directly and following was test case.

```
@Test 
   public void updateGattu() throws SystemException, SocketException, IOException {
      when(service.callGattuService("11")).thenReturn(something); 

      testSubject.updateRequest(request)

      verify(service, times(1)).callGattuService("11");
   }
```

I am not sure how to manipulate it so that ExecuterService can be detected/called.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you want to verify with your JUnit test? For now I think test you mentioned will be successful regardless of executor usage. You want to know if executor service was called or what?

Comment: After implementing Executer, it creates another thread and results not verified in same thread. Yes i want to know executer is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and straightforward solution in this situation is adding delay before verification without changing test logic because you're already checking that the internal method was called with particular argument no matter through executor or not.

```
@Test 
public void updateGattu() throws SystemException, SocketException, IOException {
    testSubject.updateRequest("11")
    verify(service, after(2*1000).times(1)).callGattuService("11");
}
```

Don't forget to spy your service. Hope it helps!

**Edit:**
In the previous version of mockito-all (1.9.5) here is similar [Mockito.timeout(int)](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verification_timeout) method which could be used like so

```
@Test 
public void updateGattu() throws SystemException, SocketException, IOException {
    testSubject.updateRequest("11")
    verify(service, timeout(2*1000)).callGattuService("11");
}
```

Comment: unable to find after(), can you tell which package is this?

Comment: Here you are [`Mockito.after(int)`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html#after(int))

Comment: Not present in my version.

Comment: Which version/artifact do you use?

Comment: <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.5</version>

Comment: Updated according your version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165956/discussion-between-fatherazrael-and-sergey-prokofiev).

Comment: Thanks. Ignorance is bliss. I mean i got knowledge about two things all together :)